# How to preserve what is on the old screen after rescaling a pygame window?

Tags: pygame

I am trying to make a pygame window that can be resized but after resizing it just deletes everything on it. So I thought of a solution on my own.

```
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),pygame.RESIZABLE)
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
screen.blit(somesurface,(0,0))
pygame.display.flip()
while True:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type==pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            old=screen
            screen=pygame.display.set_mode(event.size,pygame.RESIZABLE)
            screen.blit(old,(0,0))
            del old
    pygame.display.flip()
```

But this doesnt work. The blitted surface just disappears after resizing.

I'm using python 3.8.5 and pygame 1.9.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that `pygame.display.set_mode` does not create a new surface object. It just resets the existing one. When you're 'saving' the old surface, you're just creating another reference to the same object. If you want to save the current screen surface, use `surface.copy()`.

I updated your code to copy the screen then redraw the saved screen surface centered on the new screen. I also print the screen memory address before and after `set_mode`. You can see the screen address doesn't change.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),pygame.RESIZABLE)
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
somesurface = pygame.Surface((640,360))  # new surface
somesurface.fill((255,255,255))  # fill white
pygame.draw.circle(somesurface,(100,100,255),(320,190),50)  # draw blue circle
screen.blit(somesurface,(0,0)) # draw surface onto screen
pygame.display.flip()
while True:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        if event.type==pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            print(id(screen))  # memory address of screen object
            old=screen.copy()   # copy current screen to temp surface
            screen=pygame.display.set_mode(event.size,pygame.RESIZABLE)  # reset screen
            print(id(screen))  # memory address of 'new' screen object, same address :(
            screen.blit(old,((event.w-old.get_width())//2,(event.h-old.get_height())//2))  # draw back temp surface centered
            del old  # delete temp surface
    pygame.display.flip()
```